# The whole sequence of a convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, banach-spaces

Let $(E,\left \| . \right \|,\sqsubseteq  )$ be a partially ordered Banach space. Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ a monotone sequence (let's say $u_n\leq u_{n+1}$), such that ${u_n}$ has a convergent subsequence.

I'm wondering, in which conditions the whole sequence $u_n$ is convergent?

Edit: Here, $E$ is ordered with the order relation $\sqsubseteq $ induced by a cone  $ K=\{x\in E: x\geq 0\}$.

Comment: What is the definition of a partially ordered Banach space?

Comment: I edited the original post

Comment: @Motaka if you do not provide the definition, people will be unable to help you.

Comment: Unfortunately that's how I found the definition in the paper